# Why does the Discord bot not see the user?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

When using the command, the bot must connect to the voice channel, but in order for it to connect, it must see the user in this voice channel who calls it with the command. However, this does not happen, the bot returns a negative result, it does not see the user. What's the problem?

Code:

```
const queue = new Map();

async function execute(message, serverQueue) {
 const args = message.content.split(' ');
 const voiceChannel = message.member.voiceChannel;
 if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a voice channel to play music!');
  const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
 if (!permissions.has('CONNECT') || !permissions.has('SPEAK')) {
  return message.channel.send('I need the permissions to join and speak in your voice channel!');
 }
}
```

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: Oh, where can I check it out?

Comment: check your `package.json` file

Comment: discord.js@12.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since discord.js v12 you need to use `voice.channel` instead of `voiceChannel`

```js
const queue = new Map();

async function execute(message, serverQueue) {
 const args = message.content.split(' ');
 const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
 if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a voice channel to play music!');
  const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
 if (!permissions.has('CONNECT') || !permissions.has('SPEAK')) {
  return message.channel.send('I need the permissions to join and speak in your voice channel!');
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, now it's connected.